# How do I make this function in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, function

[This is the function I need to create in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVZlZ.png)
I have used ifelse for the first parts, but I am not quite sure how to input the third of the three equations in the piece-wise function

[image: This is the function I need to create in R]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an analytical expression of function `g`

```
g <- function(x,a = 0.001) {
  2**a*x**(1+a)*(x>=1e-4 & x <= 0.5) + (1-2**a*(1-x)**(1+a))*(x>0.5 & x <= 1-1e-4) + 1*(x>1-1e-4)
}
```

where `a` is an optional argument, set to some value by default.

You can pass a vector `x` to `g` to get a vectorized output, e.g.,

```
> g(runif(10))
 [1] 0.26534066 0.37201400 0.57292063 0.90836325 0.20149890 0.89855147
 [7] 0.94479693 0.66092938 0.62922482 0.06165721
```

Comment: Very nice Thomas. It didn't occur to me to check, but now I see it can only recurse once.

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, you are right. The recursion is conducted at most once. The bottleneck is at `sapply`, I think

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would avoid using `ifelse` here because the the function is recursive. It needs to be defined for the atomic case and *then* vectorized:

```r
g <- function(x, alpha= 0.001) {
  
  g_single <- function(x, alpha) {
    if(x <= 10^-4) return(0)
    if(x >= 0.5) return(1 - g_single(1 - x, alpha))
    return(2^alpha * x^(1 + alpha))
  }
  
  sapply(x, g_single, alpha = alpha)
}

g(runif(10))
#> [1] 0.7320931 0.9902868 0.8253122 0.5982243 0.2137887 0.6439024
#> [7] 0.8232719 0.3756205 0.2926292 0.4411532
```

Comment: So Im doing a St Petersburg paradox simulation for a class, and Im initially setting alpha to 0.001 for the first run through, should I do that before making the function or should I set the function up first?

Comment: Thank you so much by the way

Comment: @tim12345 see my update. I would probably leave alpha as an optional parameter set to 0.001.

Comment: Smart to create `g_single` to enable recursion, +1! Actually this function can be rewritten in a non-recursive manner, such that the it could speed up when passing a large vector `x` to `g`